# How can we see the BigBlueButton's meeting's attendees joined date and time from BBB's API web service?

Tags: c#, api, web-services, bigbluebutton

I could not find any answer to my question in the document below.
https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#getmeetinginfo

Maybe an experienced developer can find an alternative way or already know the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

not from the api... but you can enable keepEvents on server, or use learning dashboard in 2. to get this information

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, Bigbluebutton v2.4 has learning dashboard that does not implemented API and each learning dashboard has TTL, you can call get_meeting_info API each 5 minutes and store attendees in redis or any key-value database (for performance) and calculate attendance of users.

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some links, please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)